# Keyup alternative for dropdown boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, keyup

I've currently got a search field with `id="activityField"` such that whenever the user changes this field, an associated table updates. As far as I know, this is a result of a jQuery keyup():

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#tableFilter', function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).val()
        $('.spotRow').first().click()
    })
```

However, I added a drop-down box with HTML `<select id="activityFilter">`  and I don't know how to duplicate the keyup() behavior. When I choose an option in the drop-down, nothing changes immediately, but if I hit space in the #tableFilter input field, the table updates as expected.

Is there some keyup() equivalent I can use on this drop-down menu?

Comment: have you tried `$('#activityFilter option').on('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: Combining `change` and `click` should do it.

Comment: Thanks @Jacques -- your solution worked for me!

Comment: I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
$('#activityFilter option').on('click', function() {
   window.location.hash = $(this).val();
   $('.spotRow').first().click();
});
```

It may also be a good idea **not** to set your keyup listener on `document`. You should give all your input fields a common class, and listen on that class.

IE:

```
$('.myCommonClass').on('keyup', function() {
   window.location.hash = $(this).val();
   $('.spotRow').first().click();
});
```